# Postscript to png conversion loss

Tags: images, png, postscript, image-conversion

When converting Postscript files to PNG, is there any loss of fidelity in the converted files? The postscript files are scanned at 1200DPI.

If there is such loss, how can it be kept minimum? 
I'm using gimp to convert these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Postscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) is a programming language, bassed on Forth, so theoretically postscript files(programs) offer infinite fidelity, well as good as the rendering engine / interpreter that's passing the file can offer. There are numerous fractal / mandelbrot Postscript [demos](http://www.physics.uq.edu.au/people/foster/postscript.html), that can demonstrate this.

As to whether there is noticeable difference between a 1200dpi bitmap generated from a postscript file, via one Postscript interpreter, that's possibly scaled later by another engine to fit some physical medium, and a natively rendered Postscript file on that device, it all depends on what the intended purpose / media is, and especially on how you will be manipulating the image (rotating / scaling).